# lambda trigger : An error occurred when creating the trigger: An integration is already present on this method

Tags: aws-lambda, triggers, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I create :

- An API REST on API Gateway
- A Lambda function with a trigger on API Gateway
- A use this lambda as an Authorizer for API Gateway

I delete the trigger on Lambda function, when I try to add the trigger on lambda function, I have this error : An error occurred when creating the trigger: An integration is already present on this method.

[image]

[image: ERROR ADD TRIGGER ON LAMBDA FUNCTION]

Comment: This Question has been asked Before refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41612652/multiple-aws-api-gateway-apis-as-trigger-to-the-same-lambda-function)

Comment: It's not the same problem, In my case the function is used as authorizer but not for API/method

Comment: Are you attaching an existing API to this new lambda function?

Comment: Yes, it's the same function and the same API, just I'm removing the trigger ok lambda function and I tried to recreate it a second time

Comment: I'm editing image on description, I add the message error from server aws

Comment: Have you tried deleting the old API and creating a new one for the new lambda function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Agnij. I'm removing API Gateway and recreate it and it's I deleted/recreated API Gateway and it works